# Use a supplied dll in Visual C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I just bought a device that comes with a dll file. I want to use Visual C++ to program the device. How do I load the .dll file into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [DLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) is a library file that contains compiled program logic, just like an EXE. You can't execute it alone, but like an EXE file you can't just 'load' it into your project either.

You will need to use functions like [Load Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the library, and then [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find a function you want to call.

---

Edit:

After you clarified your question in the comments you are trying to write a windows program instead of a program you run on your device.

I wrote some sample code to show you how to start:

```
#include <windows.h>     // This is a windows header file. The functions I mentioned above are declared here
#include "mpusbapi.h"    // This is the header file supplied. It declares the function prototypes that are defined in the DLL

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    // Try to load the library
    HMODULE mpbusDLL = NULL;
    mpbusDLL = LoadLibrary(L"mpusbapi.dll");

    if (mpbusDLL != NULL) {
        // If the library could be loaded, then load the functions using GetProcAddress()

        // Load the function 'MPUSBOpen' from the DLL
        MPUSBOpen = (HANDLE(*)(DWORD, PCHAR, PCHAR, DWORD, DWORD)) GetProcAddress(mpbusDLL, "_MPUSBOpen"); 

        ...
        MPUSBOpen(...);
    }
}
```

This C code will load your libary and then attempt to load the function `MPUSBOpen`, which is implemented in your DLL.
You will need to load the other functions defined in your header file the same way (at least if you want to use them).

Comment: im getting an error when using the LoadLibrary function. 'inconsistent dll linkage'. my code is     HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibrary(
  __in  LPCTSTR mpusbapi
);

Comment: That's because you are trying to declare a Windows API function. I still don't know what you want to do, however if you can use WinAPI functions then don't re-declare them but import the header files for them. In this case: `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: I guess I should have given you more info... I am trying to create a custom program for a Linear Acutator. I'm trying to use the instructions on page 6 of [Detalied LAC Instructions](http://www.firgelli.com/pdf/LAC_Advanced_Configuration.pdf) to creat this custom program. I'm kinda novice at programming but I was under the impression that if I link the provided dll, I will be able to use the provided functions and control values.

Comment: @moesef: I edited my answer to give you an example. Please provide more information in your next questions on SO ;-)

Comment: sure thing. I'll give this a go when I get a chance tonight and let you now how it works. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: ok I tried this out. the mpusbapi.h file doesn't come with the LAC drivers.... go figure. I had to get it from [here](http://www.excamera.com/files/xess-python/xula/xstools/MCHPFSUSB/Pc/Mpusbapi/Dll/Borland_C/mpusbapi.h). Once I got it, it looks good. Now I just gotta figure out how to use the functions and what not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: btw, just out of curiosity, why is the arguement in `LoadLibrary()` `L"mpusbapi.dll"` and not just `"mpusbapi.dll"`? Also, why are there parameters to `int main()`?

Comment: @moesef: The `L` is just a symbol that tells the compiler to pass the string as a Unicode string. `LoadLibrary` points to `LoadLibraryW` by default which accepts only Unicode strings as parameters (the -A Version accepts ANSI string parameters). The `main()` function has parameters to receive the arguments provided on the launch. E.g. if you call the program via `program.exe /test` then `argc` is 1 indicating there is 1 parameter and the pointer `argv[1]` holds `/test`. It's not necessary for a sample or your program, but it's standard C syntax (which every IDE creates by default).